# Backup power supply with led

Tags: power-supply, led

My project requires a backup power supply, and I want to include an LED to determine when the backup power supply becomes active. My thought was a voltage divider to limit current to the LED, and allow the excess to bypass the LED and go straight through to the load.Would connecting a BJT as an amplified Zener where the Zener is in fact the LED be relevent?

I am told the correct way to do this would be to utilize a transistor, however I cannot think of a way to connect a transistor where I am not connecting it or an LED to ground(else there will always be current regardless of whether the backup power supply is active), or running the full load current through the gate of a transistor.Would a BJT be better here?

What is the correct way to approach this? I suspect using a transistor would be correct, I have just not been able to create a working circuit with a transistor myself!
[image: schematic]

EDIT: More info

When the 12v supply is droped it is disconnected and creates an open circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a PNP - -e.g. 2N3906; connect emitter via a 1N4148 (or any other) diode to +9V; connect base via ~ 10k to +12V. Connect the collector via a R (e.g. 10k) suitable for LED brightness to the LED to GND.

When the 12 V falls below 9V-2*0.7, the PNP will will turn on and light the LED.

The 1N4148 is to protect the E-B junction of the PNP if 12 V is present and 9 V not. If you are still concerned, you can add > 1Mohm in parallel with the E-B junction also.

Comment: A schematic might better illustrate what you mean.

Comment: Yes, it could, but I don't have time to create one & there is enough info in my comment to understand the concept.

Comment: I tried this circuit, [link](https://i.imgur.com/JcWsZwD.png)

The led doesnt light, and I am measuring positive voltage at the gate of the transistor(seems to be passing through the emitter into the base?).

Edit: Forgot to add my load. The load is an Arduino connected from between D1 and D2 to ground

Comment: (The diode D3 is backwards).

Change the 12 V to 0 V -- the LED will light.

Comment: "When the 12 V falls below 9V-2*0.7, the PNP will will turn on and light the LED." True enough, but for instance with the 12 V at 10 volts the LED will be on, but the backup will not be supplying power.

Comment: What happens when the 12V supply is not present? The PNP's base will be left floating ...

Comment: How it behaves depends on the nature of the 12 V source -- if it is not present, does it go open circuit, or just to a lower voltage ? not enough info in the Q.

Comment: I added the answer to your question in my post. The 12v supply is removed, creating an open circuit there. My thought is put a 20k restlidtor over the 12v supply so when it drops out the transistor is grounded at its base

Comment: This solution worked. Thanks! I added a 22K resistor across the 12V source so when it drops out(making an open circuit) the transistor gate is then pulled to ground activating the LED.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Electronics.StackExchange!

The "circuit never worked" because D3 and LED1 have 12v on their cathodes (11.3v realistically), which is less than the 9v they are being supplied with, so they are "reverse-biased" and do not conduct.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode) is the Wikipedia entry on diodes for reference.

What would help you 100x more than a concise answer to this particular question (as jp314 provided), is learning how to use diodes and transistors effectively.

There is a great, free series of textbooks available online for electronics study. Please see [Lessons In Electric Circuits](https://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/) by Tony Kuphaldt. If you study the first three volumes with vigor, you will have no problem finding your own solutions to questions like these.

Comment: The purpose of my diodes here is that when the main powerr supply(12v) is active, the D3 diode is revrse biased and does not conduct, preventing flow through the LED. Is my understanding incorrect in this?

Comment: No, D3 is just to protect the B-E junction of Q1. When the 12 V is > 9V, the PNP is off (B-E reverse biased), and so LED is off. When the 12 V is < 9 V, the base of the PNP is pulled low; the PNP is on, and the LED lights.

Comment: So the 12v supply is the "main" and the 9v is the "backup?" That wasn't mentioned before. When the "main" 12v supply is off, LED1 and D3 will be forward-biased and could illuminate. There are many issues with it, and jp314's solution would be much more robust.